# Receive requests with a .asmx file or a .aspx file?

Tags: asp.net, asmx, http-post

I'm setting up my site to receive info from people via text message. The way it works is they text a number, that service then sends an HTTP POST to a url I specify. I've heard that .asmx files are better than .aspx files because they don't go through the whole page lifecycle. However, I don't really understand how to get a .asmx file running, and can you even call it with a POST, ie, www.mysite.com/webservice.asmx? I know I can make it work with a .aspx file, but I wanted to check to see if there was a better way before I undertake this endeavor.

Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While any extension can be mapped to any handler in ASP.NET, by default `.aspx` is mapped to page handler and `.asmx` is mapped to Web service handler. I think you are looking for `.ashx` which represents a generic simple handler. You just need to implement `ProcessRequest` method of the `IHttpHandler` interface after adding one to your project (Add New Item `->` Generic Handler).

The `.ashx` works well if you want to manually process the request. Only if you want to provide a Web service (e.g. SOAP), you should go with `.asmx`. As a consequence, the best solution depends on the format of the HTTP POST request they send. If they send raw data in POST with their own specific protocol, go with `.ashx`. Otherwise, if they are using a standard RPC (SOAP, XML-RPC, ...) protocol, `.asmx` is probably better.

Comment: Add a "Generic Handler" into your Visual Studio project. It'll create a template and you just begin writing code the reads from `context.Request` and does some stuff.

Comment: do i call it like www.example.com/service.ashx?

Comment: Jason: Yes, like any HTTP URL.

Answer (score 0):

Create an .asmx file with Visual Studio. It should create a template with a **HelloWorld** method. Browse to it with your favorite browser and you'll actually get an explanation on how to post requests to it using various methods.

There is another type you haven't mentioned: ashx. However, in your case, a webservice (asmx) would make sense.